# Unable to run maven testng project

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

I am getting this error while running Maven project---
An internal error occurred during: "Launching TC_Testcase_001.loginTest".
org.testng.eclipse.maven.MavenTestNGLaunchConfigurationProvider.getArguments(Lorg/eclipse/debug/core/ILaunchConfiguration;)Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: Try to reinstall `Testng` in eclipse and make sure you install the compatible version. If you are trying with older version like 6.9.10 then try with `https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/6.9.10/` url

Comment: First I would recommend to try building your project on plain command line ....if this works the next step is to check if it works inside the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

TRy this

- uninstall Maven M2e 
  -Uninstall Testng
- Install Testng from eclispe
- Install Maven